# Missing drawing pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to draw some pop-up in a predefined range in horizontal scroll but it does not appear in browser, wath is wrong?

$(function(){
       $(window).scroll(function(){

```
       var popID
       var range = $(this).scrollLeft();
       switch (range) {
           case (>500 && <600):
               popID='popup1';
               break;  
       }
$('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': String( popWidth ),'height':String(popHeight )  })
  .prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

   });
```

});

Comment: maybe you should tell us first, whats going wrong

Comment: Create a jsfiddle to help us help you

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought http://jsfiddle.net/3Y7g3/ .

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(range) {
    case ( > 500 && < 600):
```

This does not do what you think it does.

```
if( range > 500 && range < 600)
```

---

```
'width': String(popWidth),
'height': String(popHeight)
```

`width:123` is NOT valid CSS (or rather, it was, but it's not anymore) because lengths must have a unit.

```
'width': popWidth+"px",
'height': popHeight+"px"
```

Comment: I would like to put some more "pop ups" but with same characteristics, am I making it wrong?